# How to retrieve Video file from SQL Server database with FileStream?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I saved a video file in a SQL Server database now I am unable to retrieve it back.

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [vid_index]    Script Date: 10/25/2022 4:09:02 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [vid_index]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'vid_index', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\vid_index.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [files] CONTAINS FILESTREAM  DEFAULT
( NAME = N'files', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\files' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'vid_index_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\vid_index_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT, LEDGER = OFF
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [vid_index].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
```

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vids]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Key] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [files] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL,

    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Key] ASC)
              WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [files]
GO
```

Then I inserted the file using:

```
INSERT INTO vids (name, files) 
    SELECT 'random', * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\video1.mp4', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

This is the code for retrieving the file- using it just return hex values:

```
select * from vids
```

> 0x00000018667479706D7034320000000069736F6D6D70343200000C786672656500000000000

I checked this and tried following along but I don't really know how to use C#
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Is there anyway to retrieve using just T-SQL commands or PowerShell?

Comment: Looks correct to me - it's `varbinary` data so it's presented as a `varbinary` literal. What do you expect to happen when you retrieve the data? Do you expect SSMS to just open up a video window and play it or something?

Comment: no, I expect it to save the file on a location

Comment: SSMS doesn't do that sort of thing. You'll be able to do it in PowerShell

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx